# How should I clone listView.item of one form to listView of another form?

Tags: c#

```
mainform main = new mainform();
            main.ShowDialog();
            ListViewItem itemClone;
            ListView.ListViewItemCollection coll = main.listView2.Items;
            foreach (ListViewItem item in coll)
            {
                itemClone = item.Clone() as ListViewItem;
                main.listView2.Items.Remove(item);
                listView2.Items.Add(itemClone);
            }
```

how should I do this one??
the codes in not cloning my listView to another listView of another form?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just reuse the same `ListViewItem` in both lists? Especially since you're removing it from the original one.

Comment: Consider data binding

Comment: i don't get it why?.
but all I know is it is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont get the value from your mainform Listview because you declare the mainform as new instance.

Put all this code to your mainform.Listview2 and rather declare a new instance of your destination listview.